# Method gets auto executed

Tags: php, oop

I created a class, made object out of it, and its only method gets called. Why is that?

Testing this on php 7.

```
<?php
class M {
    public function __constructor() {}
   function m() {
      echo "M";
   }
}
$m = new M();
```

Expected: noting shows up.
Actual: "M"

Comment: While developing, you should set your error reporting level to `E_ALL` to catch all type of warnings (like deprecation notices etc).

Comment: If you are using PHP/7.0 or later, please double-check your error reporting settings (you should be betting a [warning](https://3v4l.org/au6gf)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a method with the same name as the class it will still be used as a constructor but this will be deprecated in the future so don't rely on this

Comment: It's been deprecated since PHP 7.0

Comment: Yes, already deprecated but still overwrites the __constructor

Comment: I was referring to _"this will be deprecated in the future"_. That's not the case since it's already been deprecated (which was in the past) ;-) Other than that, you're spot on.